# mypy "too many arguments" when declaring @property function

Tags: python, mypy

I do not understand why `mypy` does not like [this `@property` method declaration](https://github.com/reynoldsnlp/lexc_parser/blob/c1f8bd8a34fa85e65e83a76caf06b3ccc3b7e095/src/lexc_parser/lexicon.py#L81):

```py
@property
def cc_lemmas_dict(self, tag_delim='+', max_cycles=0) -> Dict[str, Set[str]]:
```

When I run `mypy` on this module, I get a `Too many arguments` error:

```sh
$ mypy src/lexc_parser/
src/lexc_parser/lexicon.py:81: error: Too many arguments
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 7 source files)
```

I have searched online, but I cannot find any reason why `mypy` doesn't like this. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the point of additional arguments to a property getter? How do you pass arguments?

Comment: Can you provide a code example of how you would expect to use `cc_lemmas_dict`? Because I think you're confusing a regular method with a property getter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `@property` means that you call the method simply by accessing it (no parentheses needed). Here's a full example:

```py
class A:
    @property
    def f(self, x='+'):
        return x
a = A()
print(a.f)
print(a.f('-'))  # error
```

Note that `a.f` returns `'+'`, meaning that `a.f` was called, though we did not supply parentheses. This is due to `@property`. This also means that any additional arguments to `f` are superfluous, as they cannot be specified. In effect, `a.f(x)` (with `@property`) corresponds to `a.f()(x)` (without property), leaving no room for supplying `x` as an argument to `f`. Indeed, in the example above, the error is

> 'str' object is not callable

as `a.f()` first returns `x` which is the string `'+'` (the `a.f` part), which then is called due to `()`.

That mypy picks this up is nice!

Comment: You're exactly right. I had assumed that this code was working, but I discovered it's not used anywhere in the tests.